# Laravel 5 Mail - Gmail - AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 399:Uninitialized string offset: 3

Tags: laravel, email, gmail

so i'm trouble getting a fairly difficult time getting my mail up and i'm not finding a comparable solution out there. I’m trying to send a basic email through gmail from my website using SMTP. Everything seems correct.  Thanks for your help

•   my account is xxx@gmail.com. i've set up the two step verification on this account. the xxx@gmail.com account has password a123
•   i'm trying to send it from my email marketing@y.com.  for xxx@gmail.com 
•   under gmail-settings-account and import- send mail as
•    i have
o   Marketing     -Not an alias.
o   Mail is sent through: smtp.gmail.com
o   Secured connection on port 587
o   using TLS
•   clicking on edit info- Name:
o   Marketing
o   Email address:  marketing@y.com
•   Click Next - Edit email address - Send mail through your SMTP server
o   Configure your mail to be sent through SamsSocial.com SMTP servers Learn more
o   You are currently using: secured connection on port 587 using TLS
o   To edit, please adjust your preferences below.
o    SMTP Server:   smtp.gmail.com
o   Port: Username: xxx@gmail.com
o   Password:   OTHERPASS
o   Secured connection using TLS (recommended)

i'm getting the following error and it's taking an incredibly long time

ErrorException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 399:
Uninitialized string offset: 3
in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 399
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Uninitialized string offset: 3', 'C:\wamp\www\d\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php', '399', array('seq' => '8', 'response' => '�334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 L', 'line' => 'L')) in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 399
at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse('8') in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 277
at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('AUTH LOGIN ', array('334'), array()) in EsmtpTransport.php line 270
at Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('AUTH LOGIN ', array('334')) in LoginAuthenticator.php line 40

controller

```
public function sendEmailReminder()
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail(1);
        // dd(Config::get("mail"));

        Mail::send('admin.marketing.emails.test', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
           //i've had this with and without the from
            $m->to('test@yahoo.com', 'peter')->subject('This is how we do it');
        });
        return redirect('admin/marketing');

    }
```

Test.blade.php

```
Hi {{$user['name']}}. this is the first email we've sent
```

Config/mail.php

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' =>  'smtp',
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'Marketing@t.com', 'name' => 'Marketing'],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME',xxx@gmail.com'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','OTHERPASS’),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=OTHERPASS
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

When I do dd(Config::get("mail")); - I get the following which appears correct

```
array:9 [▼
  "driver" => "smtp"
  "host" => "smtp.gmail.com"
  "port" => "587"
  "from" => array:2 [▼
    "address" => "Marketing@y.com"
    "name" => "Marketing"
  ]
  "encryption" => "tls"
  "username" => "xxx@gmail.com"
  "password" => "OTHERPASS"
  "sendmail" => "/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs"
  "pretend" => false
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be misleading, but it is actually caused because authentication against gmail smtp servers produced an unexpected output. Google has changed the way authorization works for client apps.

Now it is necessary to retrieve an App Password for the app that is accessing Mail or Calendar in your behalf, and **use that App Password** instead of the usual password that you use for web.
More info here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: okay - looking back - that's actually what OTHERPASS. i had gone through that and OTHERPASS is 16 characters. do those 16 characters need to be separated by spaces - after each 4 characters?

Comment: All together. It has a "copy button" that copies it exactly as it should go

Comment: So the App Password doesn't appear to be it as that has been connecting as the App Password's last used date is populated so that's not it. Unless there's something wrong with where I'm entering it here which could the issue, but this is the error I get.