# Laravel Mail - Gmail - AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 399:Uninitialized string offset: 3

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, sendmail

I'm trying to send an email from my local computer by the using of swift mailer gmail driver of laravel5 but I got error the following error
Laravel 5 Mail - Gmail - AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 399:Uninitialized string offset: 3

```
enter code here
This .env setup:
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp     
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx@gmail.com  
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190112/laravel-5-mail-gmail-abstractsmtptransport-php-line-399uninitialized-string

check this.

Comment: try to change the smtp port to 587

Comment: @AshishPatel thanks for reply, but I followed that It can't be solved.

Comment: can u provide us a full error message?

Comment: $data = array(
                    'email'=>$request->email
                    ); 
        Mail::send('emails.restPasswordEmail', $data, function($m) use ($data){ 
         
            $m->to('ehr1990@gmail.com');    
            $m->subject('test');   
        });

Comment: @AshishPatel this is the errore message.       AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 399:Uninitialized string offset: 3

Comment: is this error message?

Comment: @AshishPatel yes it was error message.

Comment: means you have problem before this line. because this code is okay. check whether you have turned off ?> tag or something else.

Comment: show us that function code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MAIL_PORT=587
```

And then execute the following command to make the config changes available to laravel.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Check does your config/mail.php have same configuration ?

Comment: Yes, that is the same.

Comment: This worked for me! 587 it is.